# Changing hosts file using c++ or directly

Tags: c++, host, hosts

I want to block
     websites on browser 
    by changing hosts file . but`this code gives me " permission denied . and  can even change hosts file directly changing the permissions or by opening it as administrator.

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
 {
    // clrscr();
     char site[20],ch;
     ifstream in;
     ofstream out;
     int i;

     cout<<"1.block site \n2.unblock all site\n\nEnter the value:";
     cin>>i;

     if(i==1)
     {

     cout<<"\nEnter the Name of the Site to Block :";
     cin>>site;

     out.open("C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts",ios::app);
     if(!out)
     cout<<"File Not Found or Permission Denied";
     else
     {
     out<<"\n127.0.0.1"<<"\t"<<site;
     out<<"\n127.0.0.1"<<"\twww."<<site;
     out<<"\n127.0.0.1"<<"\thttp://"<<site;
     out<<"\n127.0.0.1"<<"\thttp://www."<<site;
     out<<"\n127.0.0.1"<<"\thttps://"<<site;
     out<<"\n127.0.0.1"<<"\thttps://www."<<site;
    cout<<"\n"<<site;
    cout<<" is blocked";
    }
     out.close();
    }
    else if(i==2)
    {

     out.open("C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts");
     if(!out)
     {
     cout<<"File Not Found(not for linux)";
     }
     else
     {
     out<<"\n127.0.0.1"<<"\t"<<"localhost";
     cout<<"\nAll site are unblocked";

     }
     out.close();}
     else
     {
     cout<<"\nEnter proper value";
     }
     getch();
 }
```

Comment: For the path, try using *forward* slashes `/` instead.

Comment: Also, you don't seem to understand what the `hosts` file really *do*. You can't have an URL in it.

Comment: i found this code on internet . i want to block websites using c++ for my school project

Comment: Just copying code you "find" in the Internet is not going to teach you anything except how to copy other peoples code. It can even be *dangerous* (as in the case where you remove the "blocking" by simply creating an empty file, disregarding what might have been in the file originally).

Comment: #include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char site[20],ch;
    ifstream in;
    ofstream out;

    cout<<"Enter the Name of the Site to Block \n";
    cin>>site;

    out.open("C:\Window\System32\drivers\etc\hosts",ios::app);
    if(!out)
        cout<<"Either File Not Found or Permission Denied, Run as Admin the EXE of the Program";
    else
    {
        out<<"127.0.0.1"<<"\t"<<site;
       cout<<site;
       cout<<"is blocked";
   }
    out.close();
    return 0;
}

Comment: Windows owns the file so you have to you have to do it before windows starts.

Comment: what about this code?  This is just to block . main problem is to edit that hostsfile . it is not being edited . And i know it can be dangerous but now at this time i dont have any other ooption . i will be doing something else in life but this is compulsary at this time.

Comment: @jdweng how can we do it even before starting man?

Comment: Seems like you'd need to run your program as administrator...

Comment: i did that @JeffBridgman

Comment: Start PC in Safe mode.  Net Services should not get started.  Then you should be able to edit file.

Comment: Here's why: when you run your app, it will start with standard privilege. You need admin privilege to change that file. Right click your app and click 'Run As Administrator' then it will work

Comment: i am doing that with admin only @asesh . and i want to tell you that i can even change the host file directly . it says this file is in use in system.